# Woocommerce Product Extra Options

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am using Woocommerce in which i need to use my product option and price according to "Boxes" i.e.

1 qty of box = 1 X Base Price,
2 qty of box = 2 X Base Price Etc that means no. of boxes will be used to calculate total price in cart. Also i have 2 variations for ex:- if i have two variation like v1 and v2 so in both boxes will be there which should be selected by customer as follows:-

v1 - Boxes - qty = 3,
v2 - Boxes - qty = 5,

So total should be as follows:-

v1(3) X Base Price + v2(5) X Base Price. Now Consider Base Price = $50.

so total should be like this,

1. $50 X 3 = $150,
2. $50 X 5 = $250,
3. Cart Total = $400.

Instead of $400 as total i am getting total of $450 i.e. Base Price is included in this, So anyone has any idea how i can achieve this task i have searched for price options but in that if i use attributes then i have to add manual price for qty of box so how can i achieve this dynamically so that price total should be as mentioned above. If Anybody knows anything please let me know.